# What is this sheet metal cutout on the PCB?

Tags: relay, identification

This PCB is from a car body control module which contains a bunch of relays to control various motors (windows, door locks, etc.). There is no RF devices on this board. This sheet metal cutout looks like it's connected to two of the relays and goes to an IC. What is it? It seems like it's some sort of current sensing device.

Additional Pictures and info:

1. The two HKFD relays control the door locks
2. The following two tyco relays control the rear windows and have a similar sheet metal cutout
3. The right two relays control the front too windows and are the sheet metal cutout in question.
4. The sheet metal has connections which feed to a IC labelled "PM25AL" which for the life of me I can't figure out what that is.
5. The sheet metal is shared with the two identical relays.
6. The windows are controlled via a 12V motor with no additional sensors on the motor. Maybe this sheet metal device is used to determine when to stop exciting the motor?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "*a car control module*"?

Comment: more photos please

Comment: A shield against RF?

Comment: It could combine several functions including heatsinking for something we can't see, as well as a shunt resistor for current measurement (OR a UHF antenna : unlikely) and a jumper between two high current points to save a PCB layer. But we can't tell from just this picture.

Comment: Looks like a current sensor. The middle and right terminals are the ‘resistor’, its value determined by the cuts in the metal; the left terminal is the Kelvin sense point.

Comment: @Andyaka body control module in a car.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Apologies, added more photos and additional information.

Comment: @hacktastical I think you're on the money. I've added more photos and information. Can provide more details on how this device works (and it's name)?

Comment: @Fredled Not if it's full of holes. It's more likely to be the opposite: an antenna looking like that but that doesn't make much sense either since it's huge.

Comment: @DKNguyen Maybe the shape is designed to catch waves emitted by antenas with such a shape, The area larger than on normal antena is meant to protect from a wide range of wavelength. Just supposing...

Comment: I think the current sensor is the right answer. Albeit it looks like a prrmitive one. How old is the car?

Comment: @Fredled around 20 years old. BMW. This module does receive a signal from an external 315MHz RF receiver (on the opposite side of the car) - not sure what protocol this module and the RF receiver communicate with.

Comment: If you trace those out, you will see the 'center-taps' goes to the connector with the heavy leads. I am certain those are current limiting or monitoring (or one time fusing?) for bridged relays. This enables reversing function to a load, from a single source power (the car battery). It will probably be the door locks or the window motors (something that reverses polarity to 'open or close' it).